# Module build failed for Saas Loader - NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am trying to use scss like below in my nuxt application. But this is not working and throwing module failed error. I have use `saas-loader` & `node-saas` as dev dependencies.

Do I need to make changes in my `nuxt.config.js` file too?

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @use "../assets/styles/functions" as f;
  @use "../assets/styles/variables" as v;

  @use "../assets/styles/components/containers/page-container";
  @use "../assets/styles/components/buttons/primaryBtn";

  .l-empty-page__content {
    font-family: v.$body-font;
  }
```

**Error**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                      friendly-errors 23:27:19
SassError: Invalid CSS after "  font-family: v": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$body-font;"
        on line 15 of C:\Workspaces\nuxt-ssr\pages\test.vue
>>   font-family: v.$body-font;
```

Comment: I think `@use` is not yet supported in `node-sass`. See https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2886. You can use `sass` package instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Comment: I have also installed sass as dev dependencies. But it's not working. Do I have to make changes in nuxt.config

Comment: No and why you install both `sass` and `node-sass`? Can you try remove `node-sass`?